# custom filed from post in the side bar

Tags: custom-field, sidebar, post-meta

I have a custom field in my post called fb_name. I need to be able to get that field name outside of the loop in my sidebar. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single post or page, you can just pass the global $post->ID:

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fb_name', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Displaying_Custom_Fields and http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Advanced_Techniques_for_Custom_Fields